# Need help redirecting double percentage signs %% using IIRF ISAPI Filter

Tags: redirect, iirf

I am trying to redirect the following URL

http://www.example.com/%%Some-Random-URL%%000001&ProductID=BIG2008_118&AEProjectTypeIDURL=APT_61

using the following code:

RewriteRule ^(.*)/.*Some-Random-URL(.*)$ $1 [NC,L,R=301]

But the redirect is not happening

for some reason I end up having the following message:
Bad Request - Invalid URL

HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

but if I remove %%  %% redirect works fine.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid URL, there is nothing IIRF can do about that.

The first thing you should do is to fix the URL, in particular the `%%`. Percent is used to encode characters in urls:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

If you have a percent character in an url, you'll need to *percent-encode* it - `%` becomes `%25`.